# getEntry() method in Hash Map uses redundant Object reference

Tags: java, hashmap

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
        }
```

This for loop in HashMap uses redundant Object reference k? Why it is required? Why can't the loop be like this? It is a trade-off between access(e.key twice) and new Object Reference?

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
                 e != null;
                 e = e.next) {

                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ( e.key == key || (key != null && key.equals(e.key))))
                    return e;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the value of `e.key` in local variable `k` might avoid the possibility on inconsistent value of `e.key` which is used twice in the `if` condition.

What if in the below condition:

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
                ( e.key == key || (key != null && key.equals(e.key))))
                return e;
```

the value of `e.key` changes between `e.key == key` and `key.equals(e.key)`?

Comment: I guess that might be taken care as said below" Hi,
>
> in class String I often see member variables copied to local variables.
> In java.nio.Buffer I don't see that (e.g. for "position" in nextPutIndex(int
> nb)).
> Now I'm wondering.
>
> From JMM (Java-Memory-Model) I learned, that jvm can hold non-volatile
> variables in a cache for each thread, so e.g. even in CPU register for few
> ones.
> From this knowing, I don't understand, why doing the local caching manually
> in String (and many other classes), instead trusting on the JVM.
>
> Can anybody help me in understanding this ?
>
> -Ulf